# mac os keychain password pops up

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keychain, xcode10

after I first learned how to code in swift I tried to run a simple app on my own iphone but I keep getting keychain asking me about a password. till now I've never seen this notification can you tell me what should I type as my keychain password?

Answer (score 1):

Type in your computer password and hit Always Allow.  That will get you passed that box and let your app load up on your Iphone.

If you've hit Deny and the box is not popping up anymore but you are still getting the same error message,  then all you need to do is shut down your computer and restart.  The the box should pop up again,  that will give you a second chance to put in your computer password and hit Allays Allow